# Why would Task object not use parameter passed to it?

Tags: c#, task

I'm using `Task` to process multiple requests in parallel and passing a different parameter to each task but it seems all the tasks takes one final parameter and execute the method using that.

Below is the sample code. I was expecting output as:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ..99

but I get:

> 100 100 100 ..10 .

May be before print method is called, `i`'s value is already `100` but shouldn't each method print the parameter passed to it? Why would print method takes the final value of `i`?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task[]t = new Task[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            t[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => print(i));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(t);
        Console.WriteLine("complete");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void print(object i)
    {

        Console.WriteLine((int)i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Congratulations, even if this issue is easy to find on the internet, you're a **very rare** case of someone who actually took some time to create a SSCCE and formulate the question clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're a victim of a [closure](http://thewalkingdev.blogspot.com/2012/04/c-lambda-expressions-and-closures.html). A simplest fix to this issue is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int v = i;
        t[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => print(v));
    }
```

You can find more detailed explanations [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596516109-03-09.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Problems occur when you reference a variable without considering
its scope.

```
       Task[]t = new Task[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
           t[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => print(i));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(t);
```

You might think that, your task will consider each i th value in it's execution. But that won't happen since Task execution start sometime in future. That means, the variable i is shared by all the closures created by the steps of the for loop. By the time the tasks start, the value of the single, shared variable i. This is why all task print same ith value.

The solution is to introduce an additional temporary variable in
the appropriate scope.

```
  Task[]t = new Task[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
           var temp=i;
           t[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => print(temp));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(t);
```

This version prints the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4..100 in an arbitrary order, but each
number will be printed. The reason is that the variable tmp is declared
within the block scope of the for loop’s body. This causes a new
variable named tmp to be instantiated with each iteration of the for
loop. (In contrast, all iterations of the for loop share a single instance
of the variable i.)

Answer (score 1):

For info, another fix here is to use the **state** parameter of the `Task` API, i.e.

```
t[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(state => print((int)state), i);
```

Unfortunately, since the state parameter is `object`, this still *boxes* the value, but it avoids needing an entire closure **and** separate delegate per call (with the code shown immediately above, the compiler is smart enough to use a single delegate instance for all the iterations; this is not possible if you add a local variable (like the `v` in BartoszKP's answer), as the *target* is the closure instance, and that then varies per iteration).